# Replace na in a 2d r table

Tags: r

I have a large table that I am reading from a csv file. I need to replace all of the NA values with -9.

My code is:

```
#Set strings to be be characters, not factors
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Import the reshape library
library(reshape)

#Read Data File
Physio_data = read.csv(file path)

#Reshape the data
physio2 = cast(Physio_data,MRN..+Order..+DOS+DOB+Last.Name+First.Name+Doctor+Last+First~Test.ID,value='Result') # more detailed

#Replace na values with -9
physio2[is.na(physio2)] <- -9
```

Because there is not a result for every testID, I need to replace the na with the number -9, a value that does not exist in the data.

When I run it, I get multiple copies of the same error on the last command:

```
In '[<-.factor'('*tmp*', thisvar, value = -9) :  
invalid factor level, NAs generated
```

When `is.factor()` is called on any value in arr (`arr[number]`), it returns false.

Can I have help with replacing the na values in a large table?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? R would not be able to handle `-9` as a value for `NA` as it would handle an actual `NA`.

Comment: `lapply(arr, class)` will show which columns are factors and which are not. You can convert them to whichever class you want and then try your command and it should work. Otherwise, you can specify the `colClasses` argument appropriately when reading your csv file.

Comment: Are the values in your `csv` source file actually blank, or do they contain character strings "NA" ?  But in any case, there's more to your `arr` than you're telling us.  Please provide a reproducible example as well as the exact code you used to read the `csv` file.

Comment: The data was reformatted  using cast, but there aren't values for every item in every column. These blank spaces need to have -9 in them instead of na.

Comment: post you data... `dput(head(data))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of the program I set

`options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Then the problems with factors stopped and `arr[is.na(arr)] <- -9` worked correctly.